# How to fix nullpointer exception

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I keep on getting a null pointer exception when i invoke the add method the code seems fine but i dont know what is wrong.

```
public class CarRunner {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    TrafficLight light = new TrafficLight();
    RoadRunnable run1 = new RoadRunnable(1,light);
    String car="car";
    for (int i =0;i<100;i++)
    {
        car="car"+i;
        run1.add(car);
    }

    Thread traffic1 = new Thread(run1);
    traffic1.start();
}

}

public class RoadRunnable implements Runnable{

private LinkedList<String> queue;

private int number;

private TrafficLight light;

public RoadRunnable(int roadNumber, TrafficLight aLight) 

{ 
    number = roadNumber;

    light = aLight;

}

public void add(String car)

{

    queue.add(car);


}
 }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception)

Answer (score 2):

Your `queue` is not intantiated.  In your constructor, you might want to do:

```
queue = new LinkedList<String>();
```

Comment: @LucasLiu, You're welcome.  Glad to be of help.

Answer (score 0):

Null pointer exception happens when you try to access a null object method or params. In your code you have not initialized the queue:

```
private LinkedList<String> queue
```

and hence facing Null pointer exception while trying to add the elements in the queue using     `queue.add(car);` in add method of your `RoadRunnable` class.

You should initialized your queue either at the declaration or in the constructor, something like:

```
public RoadRunnable(int roadNumber, TrafficLight aLight) 
{ 
    // queue initilization
    queue = new LinkedList<String>();
    number = roadNumber;
    light = aLight;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Nothing in the RoadRunnable class ever creates the actual LinkedList for the queue variable to point to; therefore queue is null and you get the NPE when you try to use it.

Answer (score 0):

You are not initialize the queue.

```
private LinkedList<String> queue = new LinkedList<String>();
```

instead of

```
private LinkedList<String> queue;
```

Reference for initializing [LinkedList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa989819%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)